# The destiny of the old photo sites?

Tags: discussion

Before Area 51 and the spawning of new Stack sites, people could (and did) pay to host sites using the Stack code. One example of this is [Photographr.info](http://photographr.info/) which, much to my surprise, is still actually alive and functional. Since I'm a mod on that site, I posted a system message (which is how I've since discovered that the FAQ isn't entirely accurate in the difference between mods and high rep, but that's another discussion) to funnel to here and warn people that the old site is now inactive.

The question, though, is what will happen with the data there? There are questions that would be closed/deleted here, but there are some good questions with good answers and so I would hate to see them lost.

Comment: A lot of the questions look like they've been re-created here. Which ones in particular are you thinking should be ported?

Comment: @mattdm - I hadn't actually gone through them, it was just something that occured to me as I was poking around. I should do that, however, since there may be answers of value if the questions have already been asked.

Answer (score 1):

You should contact our community team; we are open to importing questions so long has they have a sufficient `sum(votes)` on questions and answers.

Normally the lead is Robert but he is out this week, so try `rebecca@stackexchange.com`.